# How to enable every developer run my xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I had written a static library in objective c. Then I wrote an sample app that show how to run the static library. I want many developers to be able to run this sample app on a **real device** and **not on the simulator**(it is a BLE app and it is not possible to operate it on a simulator). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to publish it on the app store, but really you want to demonstrate the code needed to use your library, so just include the demo Xcode project with the library and developers can run it on their own devices/simulators and change whatever they wish.

This also provides self-documentation on how to integrate your library with their app.

Comment: I had include the demo Xcode project with the lib however they can not run it on their devices

Comment: @TtheTank Why is that?

Comment: one of the developers sad that he got this error "Could not find Developer Disk Image", I thought that this error across because I signed this project with my account and he don't have permission for my account

Comment: Nah.  It will contain the name of the certificate used to sign the app with, so just ensure that is the *abstracted* version (i.e. "iOS Developer" and not "My Name 123456ABC") and you should be fine.  The static library cannot be signed anyway, so I don't foresee any issues.